# Why alias could not be found in the shell

Tags: alias, csh

I was trying to set the alias for command:

```
{cutadapt -O 24 -q 19,19 -m 30 -g TATAGAATTCGCGGCCGCTCGCGATAATACGACTCACTATAGGGCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT -g TATAGAATTCGCGGCCGCTCGCGATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT -g GTATAGAATTCGCGGCCGCTCGCGAT -a CGCCCTATAGTGAGTCGTATTATCGCGAGCGGCCGCGAATTCTATA -a ATCGCGAGCGGCCGCGAATTCTATAC'
}
```

so added this into my .cshrc file:

```
alias cutqtzPro_RT 'cutadapt -O 66 -q 18,18 -m 25 -g TATAGAATTCGCGGCCGCTCGCGATAATACGACTCACTATAGGGCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT'
```

and sourced the .cshrc

```
source .cshrc
```

but it didn't work. 
shell could not find "cutqtzPro_RT" as a command.

[This link](https://web.fe.up.pt/~jmcruz/etc/unix/sh-vs-csh.html) seems to suggest to use double quote instead of single quote in the csh. I tried both, none of them worked.

Any idea or suggestion?   I am using c shell.

Comment: what is the output of `alias` command? also output for this command `which cutqtzPro_RT`

Comment: the output of "alias":$ alias
l. ls -d .* --color=auto
ll ls -l --color=auto
ls ls --color=auto
module (set _prompt="$prompt";set prompt="";eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd tcsh !*`; set _exit=$status; set prompt="$_prompt";unset _prompt;; /usr/bin/test 0 = $_exit;)
vi vim

Comment: @sp asic  the output of cutqtzPro_tag is no such a command

Comment: this means `csh` still hasn't recognized the alias.. can you try add the alias directly on your terminal and then check if it works (just copy paste the alias command from your .cshrc)

Comment: @sp asic it works in the terminal!

Comment: Try to add the alias in the first line of ~/.cshrc. Then source it again.

Comment: @林果皞, yeah, add the alias in the first line, then it works in the .cshrc file. So alias has to be in the first line (lines, say I have multiple aliases?)

Comment: I dunno what is happening in this case, but you could put all your aliases in a file, say `~/.csh_aliases` and add the line `source ~/.csh_aliases` in your `~/.cshrc` file

Comment: Because the ~/.cshrc is interpreted(i.e. source) as line by line, so if one of  your alias have wrong format/syntax, then it will stop, but doesn't change the fact of first line has been successfully alias in current session. You should double check you other alias in ~/.cshrc.

Comment: @林果皞, oh, then I guess this issue was caused by the line: setenv NGSPLOT $HOME/Tool/ngsplot:$NGSPLOT, "NGSPLOT" is an environment  variable required by a R package "ngsplot", I added a line in the cshrc, everytime I log in the system, I got complain "NGSPLOT" as a variable not defined. whenever I need to run ngsplot, I have claim NGSPLOT as an environment variable by command. so  I guess csh have problem with that line, and stop there.  Thanks!

Comment: @spasic. Hi, I guess the issue was as 林suggested, there was a line with syntax error, and csh just stuck thereafter. Tsk!